# Chrome showing Secure with SSL installed on main page but not secure on sub pages

Tags: ssl, iis

I have configured SSL on my website which is working fine on the root page and it looks fine but on sub pages Chrome says it is not secure.

Any idea? Am I missing something on Windows server and IIS?

Root page: https://www.sitelike.org/
Sample sub page: https://www.sitelike.org/similar/twitter.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the "Not Secure" text next to the URL in Chrome, and it will tell you what's wrong.

On your sample sub page, the request to get the HTML is secure, but some images were requested over HTTP so they are not secure.  Chrome will not say the page is secure unless every resource is secure as well.

In the source, here's an example of a resource that is not secured:

```
<img id="Image1" title="therealdigital.com" class="WebsiteImageSmall"
     src="http://www.sitelike.org/images/Thumb-Coming-Soon.png" />
```